# Mapping Intellij keyboard settings to Visual Studio

Tags: java, c++, intellij-idea, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Can you map/transfer the navigation/edition settings of your keyboard from Jestbrains Intellij (Java) to Visual Studio (c++) under Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Visual Studio plugin for that.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys

There is a one for VS Code as well.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings